# how to solve the single node failure of hbase namenode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm using hbase 0.94.0,I set up three machines,one for master and the other two machines as region server,also the master is namenode server.you know the hadoop namenode is a single node,so I'm very afraid of the single failure,do you have good ideas to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues to handle here: HDFS's NameNode failure, and HBase's master failure.

**For HBase:** [You can employ multiple HBase masters](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/MultipleMasters). Only one of these masters will be active, and the remaining are backups. One of the backups takes the role of the primary once the previous primary fails.

**For HDFS:** the Namenode is a single point of failure, so try to employ very reliable hardware for it, with RAID storage or some other redundant storage solution. However, there have been some interesting alternatives to backing up the Namenode, such as the [Backup Node](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/hdfs/current/hdfs_user_guide.html#Backup+Node) and [AvatarNode](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.fi/2010/02/hadoop-namenode-high-availability.html)

Plus, it is generally recommended to install HBase masters on different nodes than Hadoop Namenodes. I don't know so much about your applications, but your installation is small (3 machines) and doesn't seem to be in production, so you can actually manually restart the master/namenode. Failures are only a serious concern when many machines are being used in a production environment.

Comment: Hi Staltz,Thank you very much!and please allow me ask a silly question:How to setup multiple HBase masters,and making the remaining are backups only the primary node serving,also when the primary fails how does one of the backups could become the primary node automatically? Actually the three machines are my production environment,so If I cannot solve the "high available" problem,my plan will be weeded out(instead of Mongodb). So I appreciate you help ;)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Jake, sorry for that, I updated the answer with a link (on "You can employ multiple HBase masters"). The link tells how to start other masters, and yes, the new primary is selected automatically when the old primary fails.

Comment: Hi Staltz,I'm still be stuck by the hadoop single namenode. I did as your upper said that employ multiple Hbase masters,and that works.But I can not solve the hadoop signle namenode issue because I'm using Hadoop-1.0.2,you know backup node from hadoop 2.0,and I can not upgrade hadoop to 2.0 since I'm using hbase 0.94.0 which can't handle hadoop 2.0,so the hadoop name node single failure still blocking me.Do you have any cool ideas ;)
Thanks